# Load keras model and cache it in a variable without having to reload

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Loading a model at the beginning of my Flask application and then using it for predictions in my endpoints results in an error

'ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.'

```
model = keras.models.load_model("model.h5")

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    json_data = request.get_json()

    variable = preparePredictionInput(
        [variable], alphabetDict, maxVariableLength)
    prediction = list(model.predict(variable, steps=1, verbose=1)[0])
```

but loading keras model every time the prediction endpoint is called seems to be working perfectly

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    model = keras.models.load_model("model.h5")

    variable = preparePredictionInput(
        [variable], alphabetDict, maxVariableLength)
    prediction = list(model.predict(variable, steps=1, verbose=1)[0])
```

is there a way to fix this? this quite radically reduces the performance having to reload the model every time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your model variable is not global. Have a look at the below code:

```
def init():
  global model
  model = lkeras.models.load_model("model.h5")

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    variable = preparePredictionInput([variable], alphabetDict, maxVariableLength)
    prediction = list(model.predict(variable, steps=1, verbose=1)[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    app.run()
```

Comment: I have a video streaming project and I call the machine learning script with subprocess module in my flask application script. then the stream output is cached in redis. I use that cached image to give it as service to clients. Would it be possible if I use model as global variable and call the ML script with subprocess call?